# transition between activities overlapping content

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, android-transitions

I've implemented a transition between my activities, the problem is that when the transition occurs the content of the first activity is showing on the second one for a millisecond and then it disappears showing the content of the second activity, How can I get rid of that and smoothly show the second activity?

animation_enter:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="200"
        />
</set>
```

animation_leave:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="200"
        />
</set>
```

And that is how I'm calling it:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                TextView clienteId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pedidoID);


                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PedidoDetalheActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id_pedido", clienteId.getText()); // envia o id do pedido para a tela de detalhes


                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter, R.anim.animation_leave);

            }


        });
```

Comment: Where are you calling `overridePendingTransition` and when?

Comment: @PedroOliveira why is t matter?

Comment: @PedroOliveira I've edited the question, I'm calling it in a fragment activity when a item of a listview is pressed

Comment: Call the `overridePendingTransition` on `PedidoDetalheActivity`. Most precisely on `onCreate` just before `setContentView`

Comment: @PedroOliveira ok I did that, but I'm getting the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63179/discussion-between-jgandroid-and-pedro-oliveira).

Comment: So, is this problem solved?

Comment: @PedroOliveira Hi mate, yes it is,  if want you can post an answer so I can accept it...

Comment: What was the problem? Did those animations work?

Comment: Yes, just had to invert the value of the x from 100 to -100, like you told me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for your animations to work you have to do the following:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="200"
        />
</set>
```

This means that the activity will enter from left (100%) and will stop on the it's initial position (0%)

As for the leave animations:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="200"
        />
</set>
```

This means that the current visible activity will leave the screen from it's current position (0%) to the right (-100%)